# If a strong property has a block that refers to self, is that a retain cycle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

For instance:

```
[self.contentWrapperView addGestureRecognizer:
   [UITapGestureRecognizer recognizerWithHandler:^(UIGestureRecognizer *sender, 
                                                   UIGestureRecognizerState state, 
                                                   CGPoint location) {
        if (self.customEditing) {
        [self setEditingMode:NO Animated:YES];
      }
    }]];
```

Where `contentWrapperView` is a strong property on `self`, and presuming `contentWrapperView` has a strong reference to the recognizer block. Is using `self` in the block going to lead to a retain cycle? This is the only part I don't quite understand.

Comment: Yes, next question.  (`self` owns a block that captures and retains `self`, which in tern is capturing a block that captures and retains `self`, on and on ad nauseum).

Answer (score 4):

Yes it will lead to a retain cycle.

The workaround incase you care is

```
__weak id weakSelf = self;
[self.contentWrapperView addGestureRecognizer:[UITapGestureRecognizer recognizerWithHandler:^(UIGestureRecognizer *sender, UIGestureRecognizerState state, CGPoint location) {
    if ([weakSelf customEditing]) {
        [weakSelf setEditingMode:NO Animated:YES];
    }
}]];
```

Comment: Re-capture self strongly in the block, or you risk it going, *poof*, right out from under you in ARC.  This works for MRC, ***only*** (and not even that, as __weak is unavailable)x

Comment: Yep know the solution, but appreciate it just the same. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html

Comment: @j_mcnally Again, that only works with MRC.  Under ARC, you recapture self strongly in the scope of the block so it doesn't slip out form under you.  Your example is flawed, and can lead to the block doing nothing.

Comment: i don't see how this is any different than marking a delegate as weak which works fine in arc.

Comment: @j_mcnally `__weak` is inherently dangerous to the whole point of blocks.  With a new strong pointer inside the block, a strong self would get deallocated when the block passes out of scope, rather than when self passes out of scope.

Comment: I think in these cases you assume there's a reference to `self` somewhere else in the program.

Comment: also, empirically, weak references are retained when they are first accessed, and released when they go out of scope

Comment: so, I don't see the problem here.

Comment: @nielsbot That's not how `__weak` works.  Weak means "you cannot retain me, but when I get deallocated, I turn to nil, rather than a dangling pointer"  If weak retained anything, a lot of code would not work properly or create ugly retain cycles.  Also, only strong references are *guaranteed* to be released when they pass out of local scope.  weak references to pointers like self go out of scope when their ownership is broken to some strong object, which could be at anytime.

Comment: @j_mcnally delegates are weak because the pattern they help to define forces them to act as weakly held observers. Blocks and closures have a completely different meaning, and are not part of that pattern. If this were a delegation issue, then it would be a whole different matter.

Comment: Yeah i guess i see where CodaFi is comming from in the larger scale. Most of what I am doing is just in view hierachy stack so self would be retained until it is released. For larger worked based applications there may be a problem? I guess i'll cross those bridges when I get to them (No pun intended)

Comment: @CodaFi yes, I know that's how they work--hence my comment that the object referred to by `weakSelf` must have a reference to it somewhere else. However, if your block is entered and weakSelf has not yet been set to nil, it will remain non-nil for the duration of your block. Any other implementation would be unsafe.

Comment: @CodaFi: I disagree. How could it "go poof"? Assigning it to a strong variable could only make a difference if `self` was released somewhere between the first line of the block and later in the block. So the only ways `self` could be released is if 1) it was released on another thread, or 2) some code you are running inside block is causing it to be released. (1) is just a thread safety problem, and everything here is (hopefully) run on the main thread. For (2), it is usually pretty obvious when you are doing this.

Comment: @newacct the nature of blocks used as callbacks for threaded operations makes every last one of your hypotheticals a reality for every Objective-C developer.  To dismiss premature deallocation is ludacris.  nielsbot weak objects to out of scope and are deallocated when no more strong references are held to them, not when the function they are in goes out of scope.  That's the point of a strong self pointer.  Go ahead and see for yourself.  `-(void)func { __weak NSObject *obj = [NSObject new];  NSLog(@"%@", obj); }`

Comment: To be clear, I'm not arguing for the sake of petty reputation, or even for the sake of being right, I'm arguing because it really is dangerous to assume that __weak is any guarantee against deallocation in a block.  Especially if a future version of this method calls out to a property, then messages that property.  He could be looking at some [serious deallocation issues](http://blog.random-ideas.net/?p=160).  StrongSelf isn't a catch-all, but it's miles safer than trusting that you are the ultimate perfectionist and could *never* create a threaded referencing issue.  Future-proofing FTW.

Comment: clang also sometimes emits false-positive retain cycle warnings, necessitating this workaround when there may not be an actual retain cycle. So it is realistic to consider that the block may outlive the object referenced by `weakSelf`, and likewise possible that the deallocation of that object and the block's execution could happen in parallel. Assigning `weakSelf` to a strong local variable will at least give us consistency - either that variable is `nil` throughout the block's execution, or it references a valid, living object throughout.

Comment: @CodaFi: You keep talking about "the nature of blocks" without saying anything specific. I pointed out that with the OP's code, an issue could only come up if `self` was released in the middle of the block. Unless `-customEditing` or `-setEditingMode:` somehow causes the last reference of the object to be lost (very unlikely), the only possibility is it is released from another thread. You agree? If all the uses of this class, including all the places it is retained and released, are on the main thread, then this cannot happen.

Comment: @CodaFi: With regards to you saying that the blocks are completely different than with delegates, they are not. The problem is exactly the same. If you had a `__weak` instance variable named `delegate`, and you had code `if ([delegate customEditing]) { [delegate setEditingMode:NO Animated:YES]; }`, every problem that you are claiming exists for `weakSelf` equally applies for `delegate` -- namely, that the object it refers to could be deallocated in the middle of this code, "go poof", if the last strong reference to it disappears.

Comment: @newacct ***that's what I've been arguing for the whole time!***. That a weak object, such as self, can be regarded as in the same situation as that delegate that you mention.  The only time it gets dangerous to use is when properties of `delegate` (also self) are used, because then the block straight up dereferences a nil pointer (things get all weird and C-ish when properties are used).  And also, delegation as a *pattern* has little to do with blocks (callbacks, one could argue, are a sub-task of delegate responsibilities).

Comment: @newacct I'm not arguing about *this implementation*, I'm arguing generalities because, as the question notes, Bob is not confused about *how* to make his blocks stop retaining things, but *why* they create retain cycles.  This question is not localized, the example given in the question is.

Comment: @newacct And if you'd like to figure out what the "nature of blocks" is, I do suggest a read through of nearly every modern API Apple's written (GCD, NSNotificationCenter+blocks delivered on a queue, NSURLConnection Async and sync delivered on a queue, completion blocks on NSOperations, etc.).  Really moving stuff, really makes you think about how decoupled from the main thread most blocks can be (again, generally speaking).

Comment: @newacct, here's a "poof" scenario: the block is in a view controller and is executed on a background thread, say as a callback from a web service connection. The user pops that controller off the stack in the main thread (causing it to be deallocated) while the block is executing on a background thread. Most of the time, it's probably not an issue as the callback is trying to set properties or call methods on the controller, which would become no-ops. But it could be a problem if the callback is trying to do something based on the controller's state.

Comment: @ChristopherPickslay: right, as I said, that's when it is being released on another thread. Here, there are no threading considerations -- everything runs on the main thread.

Answer (score 4):

Think about a retain cycle in terms of what it actually is: a retention of yourself by an object that you own.

In Cocoa and Cocoa-Touch's terms, that means that any variable that you own *strongly* cannot, in turn, own *you* strongly.  This is often gotten around by declaring a property that needs to own its parent `weak`, `unsafe_unretained` or `assign`.  This gets complicated by blocks, which, acting as closures typically do, capture const or retained references to every variable within them (obviously, complicated even further by the `__block` qualifier).

Instead of looking at this from the standpoint of the block, I'll try to abstract it into an example with two classes, which is often more approachable for those in an OO lang:

Let's say I have class `MyImportantObject`, which needs to do some work with another class `MyWorkerClass`.  We'd usually want a strong references to `MyWorkerClass`, because maybe we want it to stick around so we can do a little more work later on, or continue to call the same worker method over and over:

```
@interface MyImportantObject : NSObject 

@property (nonatomic, strong) MyWorkerClass *workerObj;

@end
```

In turn, our worker needs a stable reference to all of `MyImportantObject`'s properties it needs to work (else it can't *work*!).  So what blocks that reference `self` do, instead of taking a const or retained references to every variable, they take a retained reference to their parent!

```
@interface MyWorkerClass : NSObject 

@property (nonatomic, strong) MyImportantObject *workerObj;

@end
```

What this means is that if you attempted to use `MyImportantObject`'s worker object, they'd retain each other, and neither would be deallocated properly!  Huge no-no.

By shunting `self` into a `__weak` (or `__block` under MRC) pointer, we instead get a reference that looks like this:

```
@interface MyWorkerClass : NSObject 

@property (nonatomic, weak) MyImportantObject *workerObj;

@end
```

No more retain cycles, everybody's happy, everybody gets deallocated properly when the parent goes the way of the dinosaur.

But there is one more piece of the puzzle: What do we do about the `weak` reference?  After all, let's say the good ol' compiler comes around and yanks `self` out from under you with a quick `-release`.  Because of that zeroing weak pointer, you now have a nil pointer running amok in your block.  This can lead to it literally doing nothing, while you sit there and scratch your head wondering why.  This has led to the invention of, what I will term, the weak-strong dance.

J_mcnally's example is missing one crucial step in the dance, the "re-strongification" of your self pointer.  But, why would we want to do that after we just went to all the trouble to avoid a retain cycle?  It's because our strong copy of X isn't retained by the block, it's retained by the block's *scope*.  In english, it means that our strong `self` will only deallocate once the end of the block has reached, thus guaranteeing not only a safe memory-cycle, but that it will not get deallocated out from under us.  A proper fix looks like this:

```
__weak id weakSelf = self;
[self.contentWrapperView addGestureRecognizer:[UITapGestureRecognizer recognizerWithHandler:^(UIGestureRecognizer *sender, UIGestureRecognizerState state, CGPoint location) {
    id strongSelf = weakSelf;
    if ([strongSelf customEditing]) {
        [strongSelf setEditingMode:NO Animated:YES];
    }
    //Do some other stuff before strongSelf passes out of scope.
}]];
```

Comment: Right but when would self ever be garbage collected by running code inside our block? I didn't even know ios had garbage collection honestly? I don't understand why this is an issue, if the class containing the block is deallocated are you saying the block would continue to run? How often is this an issue? I am genuinely curious. I am worried i have done some things wrong.

Comment: @j_mcnally Try not to take everything too literally.  Rather, consider the compiler inserting a release somewhere along in the line of self's lifetime.  The block may still be executing, but self is now nil and worthless computationally.

Comment: @j_mcnally It's a huge issue when threading comes into play (as blocks are often used as callbacks).  If thread a has a valid references to self, and thread b has some block work, then thread a releases self (which thread b doesn't get to see), then tries to execute the block, there is no more self.  The callback executes, but fails because messages to nil do nothing.

Comment: Like the detailed explanation, but the main thing I was getting hung up on was a nested property itself having a strong reference to a block, and how that affects things. Your comment on the question was actually more of the answer I was looking for, basically that as long as the block and self were linked by strong references, you would have the same problem. Might want to add that bit into your answer.

Comment: `id strongSelf = self;` is that a typo? Seems it should be `id strongSelf = weakSelf;`.

Comment: @BobSpryn that's what the class abstraction example was.  I tried to move away from how closures work, and into territory that was easier for me to understand when I first learned about it.