# weakSelf in enumerateObjectsUsingBlock?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Should I use a weakSelf, when calling self in the following code snippit (self.searchResults):

```
[self.restaurants enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Restaurant *restaurant, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([scope isEqualToString:@"All"] || [restaurant.name isEqualToString:scope]) {

            NSRange range = [restaurant.name rangeOfString:searchText
                                                   options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)];
            if (range.length > 0) {
                [self.searchResults addObject:restaurant];
            }
        }

    }];
```

Should I refer to weak, when calling self.searchResults in the block ?

Comment: do you mean to try to avoid retain circles? if so, it's not necessary here.

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to include that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`weak` is not required here.  The intent of using `weak` for variables copied into a block is to avoid a circular reference, and you're not at risk of that here - in part because the block isn't held onto.

Consider the following example.  Capturing self in the block which is owned by self causes a retain cycle that cannot be broken:

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject

@property (copy, nonatomic) void (^contrived)();

@end

@implementation MyObject

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if ( self )
    {
        self.contrived = ^{

            NSLog( @"%@", self.description );

        };
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Could you explain "part because the block isn't held onto" part. Different answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15647074/if-a-strong-property-has-a-block-that-refers-to-self-is-that-a-retain-cycle

Comment: Question... coming from Swift this is trivial to know, but in ObjC/ObjC++, how can you tell if a block param is escaping or not?  For instance, how do I know specifically `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` takes a non-escaping block?  I was under the assumption that by default all block params are assumed to escape unless tagged with `NS_NOESCAPE` which I don't see in relation to `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock`, but you and others are (correctly) saying the block *is* non-escaping.  But how do you know that? (Forgive my noob q. Again, I've been Swift forever.  Last ObjC was eight years back.)